# Codeception - How to get current environment configuration in Helper class

Tags: php, codeception

Is it possible to get current environment config in Helper Class in Codeception?

Now I'm passing it as `$env` variable from Cest where I use this Helper.

```
class FavoritesCest
    {
        public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
        {
            $I->loggedInIntoFrontend(LoginPage::LOGIN, LoginPage::PASSWORD, $I->getScenario()->current('env'));
        }

    ...

    }
```

In Cest I use `$I->getScenario()->current('env')`, but in Helper I can't use Actor class to get environment this way.

```
// Helper Class
    class Frontend extends Acceptance
    {
        public function loggedInIntoFrontend($name, $password, $env)
        { ... }
    }
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach to get current environment in Helper class:

```
// Helper Class
class Frontend extends Acceptance
{
    private $currentEnv = '';

    // This hook will be called before each scenario.
    public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test)
    {
        $this->currentEnv = $test->getMetadata()->getCurrent('env');
    }

    public function loggedInIntoFrontend($name, $password)
    {  
        if ($this->currentEnv == 'my-env') {
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I already found how to solve my issue in other way, but your example also works fine! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What is the other way?